converting json data to vector for better langchain chatbot results
im creating a chatbot for my university website as a project.
for the last 3 days i've been searching all over the internet how to use Langchain with json data such that my chatbot is fast. i came up with this:
from langchain_google_genai import ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
from langchain.agents import create_json_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import JsonToolkit
from langchain.tools.json.tool import JsonSpec
import json
with open(r'...formation_initial.json','r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
spec = JsonSpec(dict_=data,max_value_length = 4000)
toolkit = JsonToolkit(spec = spec)
agent = create_json_agent(llm=llm,toolkit=toolkit,verbose=True)
print(agent.run('quelle sont les modules de master intelligence artificielle et sciences de donnees semestre 1'))

it's working and it gives correct answers but the only problem its not fast because it has to explore every level of the json file each time.
upon futher research i found that in order to get the desired speed answer i need to have a vector database, but there is no clear method to turn a json into vectorDB espicially if its a complicated json.
here is a snippet of the json file which basically represent the diplomats you can get in my university:
        {"DEUST": {
    "Analytique des donn\u00e9es": {
    "objectif": "La Licence Science et Techniques en analytique des donn\u00e9es permet aux \u00e9tudiants de doter de comp\u00e9tences en mati\u00e8re d'outils informatiques, destechniques et des m\u00e9thodes statistiques pour permettre d\u2019organiser, de synth\u00e9tiser et de traduire efficacement les donn\u00e9es m\u00e9tier d\u2019uneorganisation. L'\u00e9tudiant doit \u00eatre en mesure d'apporter un appui analytique \u00e0 la conduite d'exploration et \u00e0 l'analyse complexe de donn\u00e9es. ", 
    "COMPETENCES VISEES ET DEBOUCHES": "Masters en sciences de donn\u00e9es: fouille de donn\u00e9es, business analytiques, blockchain,Masters orient\u00e9s e-Technologies: e-Business, e-Administration et e-LogistiqueFormations d\u2019Ing\u00e9nieurs dans une \u00e9cole d\u2019ing\u00e9nieurs \u00e0 l\u2019issue de la deuxi\u00e8me ou de la troisi\u00e8me ann\u00e9e de licenceData scientistTechnicien sup\u00e9rieur en SGBD R : installation, configuration et administration des SGBDWebMaster et d\u00e9veloppeur de sites web dynamiquesInt\u00e9gration du monde du travail dans les entreprises et les bureaux d\u2019\u00e9tudes ", "coordinateur": {"nom": "Pr.BAIDA Ouafae", "email": "wbaida@uae.ac.ma"},
     "semesters": [
    {"Semestre 5": 
    [" Math\u00e9matiques pour la science des donn\u00e9es", " Structures des donn\u00e9es avanc\u00e9es et th\u00e9orie des graphes", " Fondamentaux des bases de donn\u00e9es", " Algorithmique avanc\u00e9e et programmation", " D\u00e9veloppement WEB", " D\u00e9veloppement personnel et intelligence \u00e9motionnelle (Soft skills)"]}, 

{"Semestre 6": 
    [" Analyse et fouille de donn\u00e9es", " Syst\u00e8mes et r\u00e9seaux", " Ing\u00e9nierie des donn\u00e9es ", " PFE"]}]}


First you may load your json formatted data as a list of Document objects using LangChain as following:
import json
from langchain.schema import Document


def load_json(json_file):
    with open(json_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
        return json.load(fh)


data_list = load_json('./path/to/json')
docs = [Document(page_content=item["content"],
                 metadata={"source": item["source"]})
        for item in data_list]

Then, you may convert and save your docs into a vectorstore database such as Chroma as following:
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-3-small")
vectorstore_db = Chroma.from_documents(documents=docs,
                                       embedding=embedding,
                                       persist_directory="./db")
vectorstore_db.persist()

As a result, you got your docs stored in a vectorstore db in ./db where you can load over and over again quickly. Note that this is a one-time operation, and you don't need to convert your docs and save them in a vectorstore db every  time you run your application.
Also, as you may noticed, I used OpenAIEmbeddings() as embedding model, you can use any other embedding model of your choice.
I hope that this is what you're looking for and it has been useful for you.

This approach is actually the go to but you have to understand my using content and metadata is the go to method, throughout my research on the internet i found this article that will help anyone locking in how to treat JSON/CSV data: https://www.neum.ai/post/llm-spreadsheets
